# Is there a better way to check if the category has been iterated upon?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Currently, I display a category once I check to see if the category id exists, if id is null , document.write. Is there a way to write each category just once without using id?

Here is the JSON:

```
var foods = { 
"category":{
    "Meats":[
        {
            "product":"NY Strip",
            "price":20.00,
            "cost":14.00,
            "total sold": 3
        },
        {
            "product":"Ribeye",
            "price":20.00,
            "cost":14.00,
            "total sold": 6
        }
    ],
    "Vegetables":[
        {
            "product":"Kale",
            "price":4.00,
            "cost":2.00,
            "total sold": 10
        },
        {
            "product":"Sunchokes",
            "price":3.20,
            "cost":1.00,
            "total sold": 5
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Here is the code:

---

```
for(var key in foods.category) {
    foods.category[key].forEach(function(item, index) {
        // check if the id exists, if not write the category with id
        if(document.getElementById(key) === null){
             document.write("<h4" + " id='" + key + "'" + ">" + key + "</h4>")
        }
        document.write("<li>" + item.product + "</li>");
    });
}
```

Here's the result:

---

**Meats**

- NY Strip
- Ribeye

**Vegetables**

- Kale
- Sunchokes

Comment: Since the category is a key in the object, how could it exist more than once? Unless you execute this code multiple times (or have categories already in the page on initial request), there is no need at all to perform this check.

Comment: You seem to be generating `<h4>` elements as siblings of your `<li>` elements, but I'm not entirely sure. If you are, though, you're creating invalid HTML (an `<li>` must be wrapped with either a `<ul>` or `<ol>` element).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming category values are unique, the following should produce the same result.

```
for(var key in foods.category) {
      document.write("<h4" + " id='" + key + "'" + ">" + key + "</h4>")
      foods.category[key].forEach(function(item, index) {        
          document.write("<li>" + item.product + "</li>");
      });
}
```

Comment: I should have been more descriptive. I wanted to remove the id tags since I was using them as a check to see if the category had already been written. Your example is way simpler. Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you were just trying to eliminate the ID querying via the document object or not, but this just queries via a string being built.

```
var output = "";

for (var key in foods.category) {
    if (output.indexOf("<h4 id='" + key + "'") < 0) {
        output += "<h4" + " id='" + key + "'" + ">" + key + "</h4>";
    }
    foods.category[key].forEach(function (item, index) {
        // check if the id exists, if not write the category with id
        output += "<li>" + item.product + "</li>";
    });
}
document.querySelector('#output').innerHTML = output;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/phh7nsnv/1/